# minimization a quadratic form with linear constraints (Prospective method SMIC 74 method)

Tags: quadratic-programming

my problem is a ecuation i don't understand, I have no idea how to solve that, is a classic minimisation programme of quadratic form with linear constraints, here is the ecuation:

$$\sum_{i,j}^n[P(i/j)P(j) - \sum_{k=1}^rt(ijk)\prod_k]^2 + \sum_{i,j}^n[P(i/ \bar j)P(\bar j) - \sum_{k=1}^rs(ijk)\prod_k]^2$$

subject to the contrainsts:

$$\sum_{k=1}^r \prod_k =1, \prod_k \ge 0 , \text{ For all k}$$

and a example:

$\text{minimize }[(0.30 -  \prod_1, -  \prod_5)^2  + (0.15 -  \prod_3, -  \prod_7)^2
 + (0.30 -  \prod_1, -  \prod_3)^2  + (0.04 -  \prod_5, -  \prod_7)^2 
 + (0.24 -  \prod_1, -  \prod_5)^2  + (0.04 -  \prod_2, -  \prod_6)^2
 + (0.24 -  \prod_1, -  \prod_2)^2 + (0.24 -  \prod_5, -  \prod_6)^2
 + (0.27 -  \prod_1, -  \prod_3)^2 + (0.35 -  \prod_2, -  \prod_4)^2
 + (0.35 -  \prod_1, -  \prod_2)^2 + (0.20 -  \prod_3, -  \prod_4)^2]$

All these equations I got from this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016328775900488$) called "SMIC 74—A method for constructing and ranking scenarios", i must applicate this in a programming languaje (preferably web), can help me with this forecasting method SMIC?